# Keyed particles work on viewport but not in render, also they are not affected by force fields

Tags: particles, physics

When making a particle system with keyed physics, it works in viewport but the particles do not show properly in the final render. They reappear from the world center when all the previous particles die. Also the particles of the keyed particle system are not affected by force fields.

See the link for screen recording and the sample file.

The problem shows in blender 2.80 and 2.81 but not in 2.79.

I think this might be a bug in blender 2.8 but I hope you can help me to solve it.

screencast

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iHwAM4mmqMhqjmfCOXsXbziubV17bbsO/view?usp=sharing

sample file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oSP_xRjhFfo1ZBMhNjsHvpAj8H05HfQo/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I had this problem in the past with smoke, it was because you have to manually click the bake button in the cache section and cannot just play the sequencer for a bake. That could be the problem.

Comment: Cashing is not the problem. I figured out that when all the particles in the first particle system die, the particles in the second system change their position to a single point, may be the origin, so I set the life of the first system particles to a high number and changed their size instead. The problem appears in rendering only and I reported it as a bug in blender developer site but no one replied.

Answer (score 0):

What this link -- https://youtu.be/j4k7zClCcE8 -- explains is to avoid weird glitching, make two start shapes:

1. Visible shape - using your initial settings
2. Invisible shape - with a longer lifetime of the particles. Link your end shape key to this shape. Make this shape invisible by untoggling the pre-born and alive settings of the explode modifier. You can also probably disable the view from the render by clicking the hide from render option in the properties panel.

Hope this helps! I just had to rewatch that video for the fourth time to figure out what was going on with my project.

Answer (score -2):

I am experiencing the same problem. 
I did find a tutorial with a workaround implementing a third particle set. Unfortunately I have to recreate the workaround each time I change the keyed animation transform.

I hope you find this link helpful.

[Blender Beyond Basics #4: Fun with Transformations - Blender Tutorial](https://youtu.be/j4k7zClCcE8)

Comment: To make this answer useful please summarize the steps taken to solve the problem. If the link changes or goes down, then the information will no longer help anyone.